# Is there any preferred approach to constructing multiview applications in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, multiview

**Short Introduction**

I am kind of new in the field of app development using the iOS platform. Currently I'm in need of developing a multiview application for iPhone as well as iPad.

**My Research**

I've been doing some research on development of multiview applications, and have found that the general approach is to use one of the provided controllers as a root view controller (the UI tab bar controller and so on). Either that, or to write your own root view controller.

**My Problem**

The specific problem I'm battling right now is mostly concerning how to build up a more complex application which consists of:

-A log-in view (this is the very first view presented to the user upon opening the app)
-The rest of the application which should be navigated using an UI tab bar controller)

What I've come up with right now is this idea:

Create a custom root view controller. This root view controller will first present the log-in view to the user (by adding the log-in view as a subview of itself). After log-in, it should change the subview to the UI tab bar controller.

**The actual question**

My question then is if this is an acceptable approach of doing it? Basically I would have a root view controller which switches between views by adding those views as subviews of it self.

I haven't been able to really find any article that discuss acceptable ways of doing it. And my concern with my current idea is that having a main root view controller which basically contains all views of the application and switches between them could quickly become messy?

Any input would be appriciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice presentation of the post..!! :)

Comment: haha, glad you liked it :) Good presentations of questions can make all the difference in communicating the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking for similar pattern a while ago. From what I have found, I concluded that the best way to handle login screen is to inject it to main application window. So you are doing it in your `UIApplicationDelegate` class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    if ([self loginNeeded])
    {
        [self presentLoginScreen];
    }else
    {
        [self presentTabBarController];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And i.e. presentLoginScreen looks like this:

```
- (void)presentLoginScreen
{
    SMLoginViewController* loginVC=[[SMLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SMLoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:loginVC];
    [loginVC release];
}
```

Analogically, in `[self presentTabBarController]` I create UITabbarController containing actual application and then call `[self.window setRootViewController:tabbarController];`

This is useful, as you don't expand you view hierarchy unnecessary.

Comment: Aha, this looks like a neat way of doing it :) My initial concern was definitely that the login screen seemed to complicate the view hierarchy unnecessarily. Thanks for the help! :)